# Why doesn't Flutter widget Visibility's maintainSize prop work for me?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

**EDIT**
I ended up solving this by using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin which allowed me to move a widget off-screen and keep state. It is still not clear to me how Visibility.maintainSize:false is intended to work but no rush understanding that right now.
**END EDIT**

I try to toggle between two Widgets (one red, one blue container) by clicking on the screen. My wanted behaviour is that the red container shall cover the entire screen, then click, then the blue one cover the entire screen, and so forth.

I would expect the code below to achieve this, given I have maintainSize=false on the Visibility. However this does not work, the blue one always gets 50% of the screen height and the red one always gets 50%, independent of their visibility, I cannot get the visible one to cover 100%.

I would like to understand why maintainSize does not work the way I expect it to work (i.e. with maintainSize=false I'd expect the widget to get 0 width/height and the other one to expand to full screen)

Since this doesn't work, how can I do to get the wanted behaviour (without using conditional rendering with an if-case since I want the rendering state to be maintained)

```
  Widget _toggleWidget() => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (redblue == 0)
            setState(() => redblue = 1);
          else if (redblue == 1) setState(() => redblue = 0);
        },
        child: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: (redblue == 0),
              maintainSize: false,
              maintainState: true,
              child: Container(color: Colors.blue[600]),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: (redblue == 1),
              maintainSize: false,
              maintainState: true,
              child: Container(color: Colors.red[600]),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

you put two `Visibilty` wrapped with `Expanded` inside a `Column`
and you get the normal behavior each one will take 50% of the height even if it invisible

if you want to make it take the full height just do this

```dart
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (redblue == 0)
          setState(() => redblue = 1);
        else if (redblue == 1) setState(() => redblue = 0);
      },
      child:
      (redblue == 0)?
      Container(color: Colors.blue[600])
      : Container(color: Colors.red[600])
```

or you can do this

```dart
class SwitchColor extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchColor({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwitchColorState createState() => _SwitchColorState();
}

class _SwitchColorState extends State<SwitchColor> {
  Color color = Colors.red[600];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (color == Colors.red[600])
          setState(() => color = Colors.blue[600]);
        else
          setState(() => color = Colors.red[600]);
      },
      child: Container(color: color),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Since conditional rendering does't maintain the state of the component that is not rendered this is unfortunately not an option in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
...extends StatefulWidget {
bool redblue = true;
...
}
extends State<YourClass> {
...
_toggleWidget()
...
}

Widget _toggleWidget() => GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      if (widget.redblue == true)
        setState(() => widget.redblue = false);
      else if (widget.redblue == false) setState(() => widget.redblue = true);
    },
    child: Column(children: [
      Opacity(
        opacity: widget.redblue == true ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        child: Container(width: 400, height: 100, color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      Opacity(
        opacity: widget.redblue == false ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        child: Container(width: 400, height: 100, color: Colors.red[600]),
      )
    ]),
  );
```

Comment: Same result as the code snippet I posted.

Comment: then try to get rid of Expanded

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: check edited code

Comment: if you want them to be in the same place use `Stack` instead of `Column`, but all this could be done easier by transferring changes only to color